# AS3 check movieClip click with label content

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new in ActionScript 3 and I have a problem that I couldn't solve.

The situation is that I have a question (simple text) displayed in a `Label` and to answer this question, I have to click on a `MovieClip`.

How can I check that the `MovieClip` clicked is the correct answer (especially that I have a lot of them)?

Comment: use if statments... if( answer == true) onclick

Comment: [ if label1(which is the question ) && (the answer1 is clicked ) ] how to write this in AS3

Comment: What is instance name of your answer and associated movie clip?  What is your current code?